# The light from the engines on the Millennium Falcon changes colour. Why?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back, millennium-falcon

My five-year-old son noticed something in The Empire Strikes Back: When the Millennium Falcon takes off from Bespin (Cloud City) the light from the engines is red. In all other images it appears blue. Is there an explanation for that?[image: Millennium Falcon taking off from Bespin]

Comment: Bespin/Cloud City gives everything a red tint / glow. :)

Comment: I don't know if this is the reason or not, but the remastering of the original Star Wars added a noticeable tint.  It shows up in the shots from storm-trooper blasters as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although it's worth pointing out that the Falcon's engines do show a variety of colours (ranging from light blue through to a vivid white, tinged with pink) depending on their power output. In this particular instance though, then tiny on the engines would appear to be a function of the red-tinted atmosphere of the gas giant. What you're looking at is the usual white engine glow *viewed through a red filter*.

You can also see the red glow as the ship comes in to land (or whenever it's flying around Bespin).